# Getting the count of a value in a column

Tags: r, sum

I'm trying to clean up a large data set.  I have code that will return what the unique values are of a column in a data table in R.  But when I go to get the count for how many times a specific value occurs, I get an "NA."  Any help is much appreciated.

```
> RtpStateBitfieldunique<-sort(unique(train$RtpStateBitfield))
> RtpStateBitfieldunique
[1]  0  1  3  5  7  8 35
> sum(is.na(train$RtpStateBitfield))
[1] 32318
> sum(train$RtpStateBitfield==35)
[1] NA
> sum(train$RtpStateBitfield=="35")
[1] NA
```

Comment: Could you provide the output from `str(train$RtpStateBitfield)`?

Comment: > str(train$RtpStateBitfield)
     int [1:8921483] 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...

Comment: Do `sum(train$RtpStateBitfield==35, na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the counts of data, you can use the `table` function:

```
> table(train$RtpStateBitfield)
```

However this will not give you the number of values that are `NA`. In order to get a count of the `NA`'s, you can use

```
> sum(is.na(train$RtpStateBitfield))
```

Comment: Or `table(train$RtpStateBitfield, useNA = "always")`

Comment: Yes,  @DanY 's approach is better.